# Spring: Post request not reaching controller class

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am developing my first sample spring based project. Following is an excerpt from my dispatcher-servlet.xml .

```
<mvc:view-controller path="" view-name="test" />
<!-- location to scan for controllers -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.demo.student.controller" />
```

I try to do a post to the following url, but it never seem to reach the corresponding controller class:

url: `http://localhost:8080/TestProject/student/retrieveDetails`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("student")
public class StudentController {

private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class);

@Autowired
public StudentService studentService;

public void setStudentService(StudentService studentService) {
    this.studentService = studentService;
}


 @RequestMapping(value = "/retrieveDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String retrieveDetails(@RequestBody RetrieveStudentRequestBo retrieveStudentRequestBo,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) {

    logger.info("Entering StudentController.retrieveDetails()" );
```

input for post `{"testID":"1"}`

```
ERROR [400]
Bad Request
```

is the response.

Why I get the 400 error though everything seem to be in place?

Comment: Please add your controller code.Also, what is your jar file name? Which server are you running on? How do you build your app(Maven?), How do you deploy your app?

Comment: Added controller code. I am running this from eclipse and I use Tomcat 7.0. I am not using maven. I compile code from eclipse. Can you please let me know which jar file are you referring to?

Comment: to run you app on tomcat you need to build it first, then you take your <project name>.war file (which is the build artifact) and deploy it to tomcat (do you use Eclipse tomcat plugin?).

Comment: Let's see yourRetrieveStudentRequestBo class. Also set your logger to debug to see the exact cause.

Comment: What `<url-pattern>` has your `DispatcherServlet`?

Answer (score 1):

Please add slash before `student`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {
...
}
```

In addition, I expect that your build artifact will be `TestProject.war` since this is a parth of your path.

Comment: I added slash before "student" and tried - did not work. Can you please let me know , where I can see this jar file, so that I can check and confirm.

Comment: Is it a maven project? How do you build your project? If you are not sure you can answer my questions please describe me what you are doing in order to run your app on your local tomcat

Comment: Why do you think that would cause a 400?

Comment: From eclipse Project->Clean to build project. TO run the project, I do right click on project - Run as - Run on server

Comment: Project-->clean does not create a deployable war. You can do the following: 1. simply install sts (spring source tool) from eclipse marketplace and create a new spring mvc project or 2. I can guid you of how to get your war and deploy it to your tomcat. If you ask me - the first is easier

Comment: I will check and see how can I create a war and deploy it. After this, if I still get issues, I will get back to you, otherwise accept your solution. thanks

Comment: sure. I advise you to use maven as a build and dependency management tool. You might need to do some learning if you don't know it but for the long run this will make your life easier.